# как получить в одельном div обьект, балун которого, открывается при клике на метку?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Cоздал обьекты на карте

```
// Создадим объекты из их JSON-описания и добавим их на карту.
window.myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery({
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
        {
            type: 'Feature', id: 0,
            properties: {
                balloonContentHeader:
```

как получить в одельном div id="result"

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

обьект балун которого открывается при клике на метку?

Comment: Сложно понять, что нужно сделать

Comment: Сформированы обьекты на основе
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobjects_menu/
// Создадим объекты из их JSON-описания и добавим их на карту.
window.myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery({
type: "FeatureCollection",
features: [
{
type: 'Feature',
geometry: {
type: 'Point',
coordinates: [55.34954, 37.721587]

},
options: {
preset: 'islands#yellowIcon',
radius: 1
}
},

При клике на обьект карты Балун всплывает, а как сделать что бы информация прописаная обьекту также передавалась в отдельный div id="result"
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="result"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите прослушиватель нажатия на геообъекты и передавайте **properties.get('balloonContent')** кликнутого объекта в свой блок.

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
myMap.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (event) {
    var pointer = event.get('target');
    result.innerHTML = pointer.properties.get('balloonContent')
});
```

Comment: Кроме balloonContent как добавить остальные свойства обьекта?
properties: {
                    balloonContentHeader: "Павильон", balloonContentBody: '<p>Лосино-Петровский, р. п. Свердловский, Центральная улица, 1с102</p>',
                    thumb: "/wp-content/themes/attila/map/public/img/thumbs/94.jpg",
                    img1: "/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/9K9CF6y6oHs.jpg",
                    description: "9 x 7,5 м.<br>Срок реализации 45 дней<br>Стоимость 2,7млн "
                },

Comment: А в чём сложность собирать тем же образом все поля, которые вы задаёте для балунов? balloonContentHeader, balloonContentBody Вроде все аналогичным запросом получить можно

Comment: Нет понимания как их выводить в наборе типа 'balloonContent'+' description'+' thumb'

Comment: result.innerHTML = '<p>' + pointer.properties.get('description') + '</p>'+ и т.д.

Comment: Ну да, примерно так, разбивая строки <br>, и выводить. Или таблицей: "<table><tr>" + pointer.properties.get('balloonContentHeader') + "</tr><tr>" + pointer.properties.get('balloonContentBody') + "</tr><tr>" + pointer.properties.get('balloonContentFooter') + "</tr></table>" Если не подходит, вы хоть пример кода покажите на том же jsbin.com , чтобы понимать, что не так.

Comment: спасибо большое, так и вывел
result.innerHTML = '<p>' + pointer.properties.get('description') + '</p>'+ и т.д.